# not counting duplicate ids month by month

Tags: sql, duplicates, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to count the number of ids, but in a special way. For example, if the id is counted in April, I don't want to count that id again in May. so excluding id's that have been counted in previous months.
this is the query I am using.

select store, monthname(created_at), count(distinct customer_id) from a group by 1,2;

Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count the first time a customer is seen.  One method is two levels of aggregation:

```
select store, date_trunc('month', min_created_at), count(*)
from (select store, customer_id, min(created_at) as min_created_at
      from a
      group by store, customer_id
     ) c
group by 1, 2;
```

Note:  `monthname()` is not appropriate for defining a month, because it does not take the year into account.  If you really do want to ignore the year, you can use `monthname()` but that seems unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this sql statement helps!

select store, monthname(created_at), count(distinct customer_id)
from a
where monthname(created_at)=MONTHNAME(current_date())
group by 1,2;